# Why is "qui" needed in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire

From a wikipedia article I was reading:

> L'escadre française commandée par le contre-amiral Louis Dubourdieu
>   bombarde la ville jusqu'au lendemain en détériorant sérieusement les
>   infrastructures de la ville, dont la Grande Mosquée **qui** est gravement
>   touchée.

I don't understand the purpose of *qui*. I would have just written it as "dont la Grande Mosquée est gravement touchée," as in "whose Grand Mosque was strongly affected." (roughly)

While I still understand the sentence's meaning, I don't understand why *qui* is grammatically needed here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, removing the *qui* would indeed (and rather exceptionally) result in a grammatically valid sentence, and even one with a relatively identical meaning. However here *dont* is not meant to be the prepositional relative pronoun, but a preposition with a different meaning and the last part of the sentence in fact translates as

> *[...] amongst them the great mosque, which is severely damaged.*

Mind you the french would read better with a comma before *qui*.

Answer (score 3):

French is my mother language, I'm not a grammatical expert, I bet someone will give you a better answer.

That "qui" is needed to point-out that the "Grande mosquee" was hit during this attack.
Whitout that "qui", the sentence would look like *"[...] les infrastructures de la ville, dont la Grande Mosquée, gravement touchée."*

In this case, we dont know if the mosquee was hit during that attack or earlier.
Plus, its not really beautiful and I'm not even sure that this sentence is correct in French.

What you would have written "*dont la Grande Mosquée est gravement touchée*"
isn't saying "whose Grand Mosque was strongly affected." but "whose Grand Mosque **is** strongly affected"

I hope this answer will helps, I hope someone will give you a more technical reply, involving grammatical rules.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!!! Have your first upvote.

Answer (score 1):

> - L'escadre française commandée par le contre-amiral Louis Dubourdieu bombarde la ville jusqu'au lendemain en détériorant sérieusement les infrastructures de la ville, *dont* la Grande Mosquée *qui est* gravement touchée.
> - L'escadre française commandée par le contre-amiral Louis Dubourdieu bombarde la ville jusqu'au lendemain en détériorant sérieusement les infrastructures de la ville, dont la Grande Mosquée gravement touchée.
> - L'escadre française commandée par le contre-amiral Louis Dubourdieu bombarde la ville jusqu'au lendemain en détériorant sérieusement les infrastructures de la ville,  la Grande Mosquée *est* gravement touchée.

La première phrase se focalise sur la Grande Mosquée et insiste sur la gravité des dégâts.

La deuxième rend compte d'un évènement sans plus, sans emphase, sans émotion particulière, dans le style des dépêches [*AFP*](http://www.afp.com/) ; dans ce cas, on utilise la [*contraction de texte*](http://www.erudit.org/culture/qf1076656/qf1219128/45568ac.pdf) en enlevant les mots qui renvoient à la même idée, au même objet ou qui peuvent être supprimés sans altérer le sens du message.

Remarque : le *qui*, sujet du *est*, est ajouté parce que la Grande Mosquée est reliée au texte précédent par le *dont*, elle est un complément qui ne peut pas être en même temps sujet du *est*.

Dans la troisième phrase la Grande Mosquée est sujet de *est* en supprimant la liaison littéraire *dont*. La seconde partie de la phrase pourrait être disjointe : la virgule pourrait être remplacée par un `;` ou par un `.`

Comment: Vraiment?? On peut omettre *qui* **et** *est*, comme dans ta deuxième phrase? Même utilisant *contraction de texte*, ça m'apparait comme très bref.

Comment: @Aerovistae L'un sans l'autre n'ont aucun sens. J'ai été surpris en découvrant cette nécessité car cela bouscule la prosodie  usuelle. *... la Grande Mosquée gravement touchée* précédée de *dont* qui apporte le verbe de la séquence précédente, ou suivi d'une séquence avec un verbe comme *n'est plus que ruines* est une construction qui répond au grand principe du sujet (avec fioriture) - verbe - complément (auquel semble s'ajouter ici un complément adverbial complété d'un adjectif ; mais n'étant pas grammairien et encore moins académicien, je vous laisse trouver le bon étiquetage).